# sql server installation error

Tags: server, sql

When I try to install SQL Server, I get this error:

```
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 mssql-server : Depends: libcurl3 but it is not going to be installed
                Depends: openssl (<= 1.1.0)
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

How can I fix it?

Answer (score 0):

Try installing the `libcurl3` and `openssl` packages if you haven't already. If that does not work, try the following:

- `apt autoclean`
- `apt -f install`
- `dpkg --configure -a`
- `apt -f install`

Then try installing `mssql-server` again